# Blender addon coding, how do I update a list when I select from another?

Tags: python, blender

I have 2 dropdowns, one shows group names, and the other shows objects in the group.  I don't know much about python callbacks, or how blender calls events.  But I want to update the objects dropdown when I select a group from the list. 
Can someone give me some pointers or tips on blender programming?  I'm quite new to it, and Python in general.

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: No, just a couple of UI elements ecapsulated in a LayoutPanel class. Ie;     
       `col.menu(CustomMenu.bl_idname, 'Group', icon='SCRIPTWIN')      
        col.menu(CustomMenu.bl_idname, 'Items', icon='SCRIPTWIN')`

Comment: I was thinking I could just update an enum, using a prop_menu_enum for the dropdown. Ie;              
`col.prop_menu_enum(context.scene, 'ImgSize', icon='SCRIPTWIN')
enum_size_items = [
                ('OPT1','obj1','',1),
                ('OPT2','obj2','',2),
                ('OPT3','obj3','',3),
                ('OPT4','obj4','',4)]`